# Is this data model a list or tree?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, data, trees, list

Using python syntax with below environment diagram, teacher taught us that there are 11 trees(orange boundary) in this diagram, including leaf.

### [image]

It has been taught [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/assets/slides/12-Trees_1pp.pdf),

*lists are represented as a row of index-labeled adjacent boxes, one per element. Each box either contains a primitive value or points to a compound value. For example:*

```
nested_list = [   [1, 2],    [],     [[3, False, None],[4, lambda : 5]]   ]
```

*tree is either a single value called a **leaf** or a sequence of **trees**. Typically some **type restriction** is placed on the leaves. E.g a tree of numbers. For example:*

```
tree = [     [1, [2], 3, []],      [[4], [5,6]],       7    ]
```

My question:

In general, Can a tree have heterogeneous type data? for example: Can I say, `abc = [1, 2, 3, 4, lamda: 5]` a tree with 5 leaves?

*Note: Intention is to understand, whether tree can have heterogeneous type data*

Comment: Actually trees don't have leafs, trees have branches and branches have either smaller branches or directly leafs, so I would say abc isn't a tree, but I guess that's just a question of language.

Comment: @LaurentS.  tree don't have leaves? what does that mean? Can you show your tree diagram with data in it?

Comment: That was my way of saying that if your tree only have leaves, it doesn't actually look like a tree. As long as no nesting is implied, I wouldn't actually speak of a tree. The same way you probably wouldn't call a real-life bag of leaves nor a single branch, a tree...

Answer (score 8):

This heavily depends on definition of *list* and *tree*.

Mathematically *list* doesn't mean anything and *tree* is just special subset of a *graph*.

Inferring from your question, your teacher's definition of *tree* is *nested lists*. In which case, list of nesting depth of 0 is still a tree. So

*abc = [1, 2, 3, 4]*

Is a tree.

In this case, the `list` is subset of `tree`. Every list is a tree, but not every tree is a list. If you have operation that only works on list, then only instances that are lists can be used as parameter, but not when they are just tree.

At least that's how it would work in math. In case of this python "pseudoexample" there is not really much difference between tree and a list. I believe you are getting confused, because your teacher is just using Python structures as definitions and not defining the terms in unambiguous mathematical terms.

Comment: [1,2,3,4] could be thought of as a tree whose children are 4 leaves, yes.  More traditionally, it is also a list with 4 items (even if some of those items were to contain themselves lists).

Comment: @Neil It is also a list with four items? then why we perceive the single data model with two names 'list' and 'tree'. There should be some uniqueness between two data models, before designating name to each data model.

Comment: @overexchange See my edit.

Comment: @overexchange: what makes you think that we perceive that model with two names? I can think of at least five: it is a list, it is a tree (because every list is a tree), it is a forest (because every tree is a forest), it is a DAG (because every forest is a DAG), it is a graph (because every DAG is a graph).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh ok, I got you. Currently I know about tree/list sequential data models. Are graph/forest/DAG are also sequential data models?

Comment: @overexchange They can be, yes.  It depends entirely on how you want to represent it.  Technically a tree can be represented as just a list of pairs indicating the start and end nodes.  You can and *should* represent the data in the way easiest for you to manage and conceptualize.

Comment: As observed, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` can be seen as a tree with one root node and 4 leaves. In this case you speak of an unranked tree: each node can have an arbitrary number of children. Such an unranked tree is isomorphic to a binary tree (ranked tree in which each node has exactly two, possibly empty, child-trees) if you think about the Lisp representation: nodes are either atoms or cons-cells. Bottom line (as pointed out by others): the data in the examples can be considered as trees according to different definitions of tree.

Comment: @Giorgio Is `[1, 2, 3, 4, lamda: 5]` is a list or tree?

Comment: @overexchange: How do you define sequential? Partially ordered? Then DAGs (and trees and lists as well, since they are special cases of DAGS) are sequential.

Comment: @overexchange: Lists **are** trees. `[1, 2, 3]` is isomorphic to `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, or :(1, :(2, :(3, [])))`, which is a tree.

Comment: @Giorgio In the query, it says, there is type restriction in leaves. what does that mean?

Comment: The type restriction means that one expects all leaves to have the same type. But in a language like Python you can also have leaves of any type.

Comment: @Giorgio But in the diagram of above query, node having data `7`  is leaf node or non-leaf node? What is a leaf node in a tree?

Comment: @overexchange: Yes, the node containing a `7` is a leaf. Leaf nodes are nodes that do not have any children.

Comment: @Giorgio oh you mean `tree[2]` is leaf node and `tree[0]` or  `tree[1]` is non-leaf node in the above diagram? Are you considering each element of any list pointed by `tree` as node ?

Comment: "Are you considering each element of any list pointed by tree as node ?": tree points to one list only. This list is a node but not a leaf node. It contains three subnodes, the first two are internal nodes, the third is a leaf-node. And so on. The leaf-nodes of the tree are therefore the one marked by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and the empty list.

Comment: @Giorgio i got u, [this](https://github.com/shamhub/paradigms_using_python/blob/master/tree/scn.png) is what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the issue by using lambda expressions in the structure. The expression `lambda:5` is neither a list nor a number. It is a function. So the data structure in your example is not a tree of numbers, since one of the leaves is a function rather than a number.

But disregarding the lambda, the expression [1, 2, 3, 4] is a list, and *also* a tree according the definition of tree you provide (because it is a sequence of trees, where each tree is a leaf). This is not a contradiction, since according to the definition you provide, any list will also be a tree.

Comment: How can list be a tree? if list is something like `[1, 2, lambda: 5]`? Because my teacher's  definition of tree says that leafs have type resriction  placed on the leaves

Comment: @overexchange: Depends on the type restriction, but if the type restriction is that the leaves should be numbers, then [1, 2, lambda: 5] is not a valid tree according to your definition, since a lambda is neither a sequence nor a number.

Comment: In general, can a tree have heterogenuos type data?

Comment: @overexchange: Sure, a JSON structure for example is a tree structure with leafs of various types.

Comment: I think JSON leaves have key value pairs.